# Spotify Android API ACCOUNTS_INVALID_APP_ID

Tags: android, spotify

So I've used [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/) tutorial to help me create an App that communicates with my spotify, but I always get the following error:

{"message":"ACCOUNTS_INVALID_APP_ID:INVALID_REQUEST: Invalid app identifier (iOS Bundle ID, Android Key Hash)"}

I've registered only a Android ID and also the corresponding fingerprint I found out using the keytool, but it still tells me that my bundle ID is apperently from iOS. Since I have no own website I used a packagename that was suggested to me via different tutorials, which is me.MYNAME.APPNAME

So what suggests Spotify that I'm doing anything on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone actually having the same problem:
I just deleted the Spotify App on my Dashboard and created a new one and everything worked even though I gave it the same input. It may be weird but at least it now works

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for the answer of this question. This is because of SHA1 key. For debug, each machine will have its own SHA1 key. Better to have a single debug certificate on all machine to make it functional for each build.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem silly, but make sure that the SHA1 Hash letters are in uppercase.

[SHA1 Hash in uppercase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLFUp.png)

Comment: It's important to take into consideration more information regarding the problem. The answer you are providing is quite wide and maybe is not helping the user with their problem.